# Out of memory exception..in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to get images from photo library of windows phone 8..and for the first time it is working fine. i get the image from **Camera Roll** folder for first time but when i tried to take the pictures from album Saved Picture it throws the Out Of Memory Exception.. i am not getting why is this happening. Any help is appreciated.

```
    MediaImage mediaImage = new MediaImage();


    BitmapImage image;
    private void Panorama_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Panorama obj = sender as Panorama;
        PanoramaItem objPanoramaItem = (PanoramaItem)obj.SelectedItem;
        string FolderName = objPanoramaItem.Header.ToString();
        PictureAlbum AlbumFolder = allAlbums.Where(album => album.Name == FolderName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (FolderName == "Camera Roll")
        {
            if (ImageListCameraRoll == null)
            {
                ImageListCameraRoll = new ObservableCollection<MediaImage>();



                var CameraRollPictures = AlbumFolder.Pictures;

                foreach (var picture in CameraRollPictures)
                {
                    mediaImage = new MediaImage();
                    image = new BitmapImage();
                    image.SetSource(picture.GetImage());
                    mediaImage.ImageFile = image;
                    mediaImage.ImageName = picture.Name;
                    ImageListCameraRoll.Add(mediaImage);
                }
            }
            ListboxCameraRoll.ItemsSource = ImageListCameraRoll;
        }
        if (FolderName == "Saved Pictures1")
        {
            if (ImageListSavedPictures == null)
            {
                ImageListSavedPictures = new ObservableCollection<MediaImage>();
                var SavedPictures = AlbumFolder.Pictures;
                foreach (var picture in SavedPictures)
                {
                    mediaImage = new MediaImage();
                    image = new BitmapImage();
                    image.SetSource(picture.GetImage());
                    mediaImage.ImageFile = image;
                    mediaImage.ImageName = picture.Name;
                    ImageListSavedPictures.Add(mediaImage);
                }
            }
            ListboxSavedPictures.ItemsSource = ImageListSavedPictures;
        }
}
```

what i am doing here is trying to get the pictures on panorama item changed event. Panorama item is based on different folders in photo library..

Comment: Not very familiar with the album APIs, but it looks to me like you're loading full resolution versions of all images in a folder to memory. Is that what you're meaning to do, since it will probably take quite some memory if the folder is large.

Comment: so is thr any other way..like compress or something

Comment: On which line you are getting error?

Comment: just got solve..and thanks for help ..to every one

Comment: Hi loop share your solution, so that it will help to others.

Comment: @Noorul The ans provided below is what i actually doing wrong. but i have got it right before the ans came.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loading all images from a folder into memory may take a lot of memory space. Unless you *really* need the full size images, I'd suggest using [GetThumbnail()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434150.aspx) instead to load low resolution versions of the photos. You can always go back to the originals once the user has selected which photos to perform an action on.

```
image.SetSource(picture.GetThumbnail());
```